# Assign variable from Smarty to PHP

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I'm using Smarty for eMail-Templates and I want to have mail subject in one place with the body template.

My first try was to set the subject with

```
{assign var="subject" value="mySubject"}
```

and access it with

```
$smart->getTamplateVars();
```

but subject is nowhere to be found.

My current working solution is:

```
{php}
    global $subject;
    $subject = "My Subject";
{/php}
```

But using SmartyBC and {php} feels wrong.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't assign variables in Smarty and then use it by PHP. The aproach is to assign variables in your controller and then display it in your view. You should really read about MVC pattern. Moreover, don't use globals it is really bad solution. {php} tag is very optional and should not be abused.

http://www.smarty.net/sampleapp1 under this link you will find sample app check it and look how it should look like.

Comment: I think in this case is the E-Mail the view and as the subject is part of the E-Mail it should be part of the template. I now myself that {php} and global is not the way to go, but do you have another solution?

Comment: Yep in controller action assign subject to email render it and send as email. I still don't see necessity to assign it in template file.

Comment: This would mean that part of the view (the subject) is in the controller and the designer has to edit it there.

Comment: Part of subject could be send via form or it could be in DB.